# Viewing images open in GIMP side by side

Tags: gimp

I have one instance of [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) open. I have opened two images. They appear as separate tabs by default:

[image: two images open in two tabs tabs in default]

Is there a way to view the open images side by side? Can I "undock" one of the open windows or manipulate the windows in way? I would like to view them side by side for dual view photo editing and comparisons.

OS: Windows 10   ||   GIMP: 2.10.8

---

A way to do this in Photoshop was discussed in [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/248616/open-two-copies-of-the-same-file-side-by-side-in-photoshop).

Answer (score 3):

Turn it off from the pulldown menus: Windows -> Single-Window Mode

[image]